# Hall $\pi$-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading "Further Algebra and Applications" (Paul M. Cohn) and it is written that "if $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ and $f$ is any homomorphism from $G$, then *clearly* the image $Hf$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $Gf$.

Can anyone help me clarify that *clearly*? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ is a hall $\pi$-subgroup exactly when $|H|$ has prime divisors in $\pi$, and its index $[G:H]$ contains no divisors in $\pi$. Now let's hit $G$ with a surjective hom $f$.

Then $|Gf| = |G|/|K|$ where $K$ is the kernel. For simplicity, if $K \leq H$, then $|Hf| = |H|/|K|$, and the primes in $|Hf|$ are still in $\pi$, and the index $[Gf:Hf] = [G:H]$, and so contains no primes from $\pi$ either.

If $K \not \leq H$, there is a similar (but slightly more complicated) argument to be made.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: It does help! Thanks :)

Comment: ..actually, can you give me a hint for the second case?

Comment: Of course! If $K \not \leq H$, then $|Hf| = |H|/|H \cap K|$ - again, we've potentially lost some factors of $|H|$ in doing this division, but $[Gf:Hf]$ still uses no primes in $\pi$.